# Spring-MVC 3.1: Preventing A JSP From Being Cached In A Browser

Tags: jsp, caching, spring-mvc, browser-cache

I'm using Spring 3.1 for my webapp.   I'm trying to stop just one JSP from being cached in the user's browser to prevent them from reaching it via their back button.

I've had good luck using these settings in Servlets that print out an HTML page:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-control", "no-cache, no-store");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");                
response.setHeader("Expires", "-1");
```

I haven't been able to get those some calls to work in controller function( which is usually invoked from a redirect):

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/error")
    public String error(HttpSession session,HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap model){
        logger.debug("started");

        response.setHeader("Cache-control", "no-cache, no-store");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");                
        response.setHeader("Expires", "-1"); 

        String status_message = (String)session.getAttribute("status_message");
        status_message = (status_message == null) ? "" : status_message.trim();
        session.removeAttribute("status_message");
        model.put("status_message",status_message);

        return "error";
    }
```

I also tried putting the calls in my JSP like this( above and below the include for the header file ):

```
<%@ include file="header.jsp" %>
<%
   response.setHeader("Cache-control", "no-cache, no-store");
   response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");                
   response.setHeader("Expires", "-1"); 
 %>
     <!-- content -->

<%@ include file="footer.jsp" %>
```

I also tried putting the calls in my header file that is included in every JSP, though I only want one JSP not stored....just to see if I could make it work.  It did not work:

```
<%@ page language = "java" session = "true" import = "java.util.*, java.text.*" %>
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix = "f" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">

<title>Acme Customer Service</title>
    <link rel = "StyleSheet"  href = "../nsd/css/nsd.css"   type = "text/css"/>
</head>
```

I also tried experimenting with toggling the "Expires" setting between 0 and -1.  No dice.

Any ideas on how I can get a single JSP to being cached in the user's browser?

Thanks much in advance

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to extend [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/HandlerInterceptorAdapter.html) and if the requested uri matches your controller's uri, then add the headers in the postHandle method. You could also set an attribute in the HttpServletRequest in the controller and then check for it in the interceptor. You could also use [spring-mvc-util](https://github.com/rgladwell/spring-mvc-util) to create an interceptor for a given uri.

Comment: I'm a bit new to Spring.  Could you post an example?  Does Spring override my ability to expire the pages the normal way?

Answer (score 0):

Make the url unique each time: Add a get parameter to the url to include the epoch seconds, or some other unique string.

So you'll end up with something like: http://www.google.com?param1=val1&secs=2342314234